# Removing control characters from a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, unicode, non-printing-characters

I currently have the following code

```
def removeControlCharacters(line):
    i = 0
    for c in line:
        if (c < chr(32)):
            line = line[:i - 1] + line[i+1:]
            i += 1
    return line
```

This is just does not work if there are more than one character to be deleted.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

There are *hundreds* of control characters in unicode.  If you are sanitizing data from the web or some other source that might contain non-ascii characters, you will need Python's [unicodedata module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html).  The `unicodedata.category(…)` function returns the [unicode category code](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#GC_Values_Table) (e.g., control character, whitespace, letter, etc.) of any character.  For control characters, the category always starts with "C".

This snippet removes all control characters from a string.

```py
import unicodedata
def remove_control_characters(s):
    return "".join(ch for ch in s if unicodedata.category(ch)[0]!="C")
```

---

Examples of [unicode categories](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#GC_Values_Table):

```
>>> from unicodedata import category
>>> category('\r')      # carriage return --> Cc : control character
'Cc'
>>> category('\0')      # null character ---> Cc : control character
'Cc'
>>> category('\t')      # tab --------------> Cc : control character
'Cc'
>>> category(' ')       # space ------------> Zs : separator, space
'Zs'
>>> category(u'\u200A') # hair space -------> Zs : separator, space
'Zs'
>>> category(u'\u200b') # zero width space -> Cf : control character, formatting
'Cf'
>>> category('A')       # letter "A" -------> Lu : letter, uppercase
'Lu'
>>> category(u'\u4e21') # 両 ---------------> Lo : letter, other
'Lo'
>>> category(',')       # comma  -----------> Po : punctuation
'Po'
>>>
```

Comment: Upvoting, as this is the only correct answer for unicode-aware applications.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be: return "".join(ch for ch in s if unicodedata.category(ch)[0]!="C") ?

Comment: This is a very reliable solution of removing non-printable characters, thanks!

Comment: Should the "Zl" category be included too? It's not clear to me what U+2028 really does, but I just had the misfortune of running into it...

Comment: This the only correct answer..

Comment: This removes way more than just control characters.  Importantly, this also removes characters in the `Cn` category, which are just "unassigned" characters (currently ~75% of available unicode points).  Usually, you don't want these in your strings anyway, but in some cases the distinction matters.

Answer (score 31):

You could use [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) with the appropriate map, for example like this:

```
>>> mpa = dict.fromkeys(range(32))
>>> 'abc\02de'.translate(mpa)
'abcde'
```

Comment: I'd suggest not using `map` as a variable name.

Comment: Note, though, that this nukes newlines.

Comment: This code isn't working. I keep getting `TypeError: expected a character buffer object` error. Python 2.6.

Comment: @user1476056: than you need to use newer version of Python. question is clearly tagged `python-3.x`

Comment: I think this should be `dict.fromkeys(range(33))` since `range` is upper-bound exclusive.

Comment: @dustinfarris That would include character 32, which is space.

Comment: newline is a control character if i am not mistaken?

Comment: Your code doesn't work, and terminates with `expected a character buffer object` on Python 2.7

Answer (score 23):

Anyone interested in a regex character class that matches any Unicode [control character](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#control-characters) may use `[\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f]`.

You may test it like this:

```
>>> import unicodedata, re, sys
>>> all_chars = [chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode)]
>>> control_chars = ''.join(c for c in all_chars if unicodedata.category(c) == 'Cc')
>>> expanded_class = ''.join(c for c in all_chars if re.match(r'[\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f]', c))
>>> control_chars == expanded_class
True
```

So to remove the control characters using `re` just use the following:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f]', '', 'abc\02de')
'abcde'
```

Comment: One difference between this and the first answer is that this only works for `Cc` while that one works for `C*`

Answer (score 19):

This is the easiest, most complete, and most robust way I am aware of. It does require an external dependency, however. I consider it to be worth it for most projects.

```
pip install regex

import regex as rx
def remove_control_characters(str):
    return rx.sub(r'\p{C}', '', 'my-string')
```

`\p{C}` is the [unicode character property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property) for control characters, so you can leave it up to the unicode consortium which ones of the millions of unicode characters available should be considered control. There are also other extremely useful character properties I frequently use, for example `\p{Z}` for any kind of whitespace.

Comment: Agreed. The `regex` library will have up-to-date unicode info, compared to the built-in unicodedata module.

Comment: On a side note, I'd argue strongly for avoiding things like `import regex as re` on general principals, particularly when it collides with Python's stdlib. This approach obfuscates dependencies in code, adding an unnecessary confusion node vis-a-vis readability. Sticking with `import regex` and using `regex` within your code makes everything more clear. Aside from that, +1 on this answer. Upvoting.

Comment: @ChrisLarson I agree! changed.

Comment: Can you please write on how to do it for a column of a dataframe? I am trying my_dataframe['column_1'].str.replace(r'\p{C}', '  ', regex=True). It gives error "error: bad escape \p"

Comment: @SyedMdIsmail If `my_dataframe['column_1'].str` is your input string, you would use `rx.sub(r'\p{C}', '', my_dataframe['column_1'].str)` to return the cleaned string.

Answer (score 9):

Your implementation is wrong because the value of `i` is incorrect. However that's not the only problem: it also repeatedly uses slow string operations, meaning that it runs in O(n<sup>2</sup>) instead of O(n). Try this instead:

```
return ''.join(c for c in line if ord(c) >= 32)
```

Comment: at least twice as slow than `str.translate`

Comment: @ben: it's all well and readable until `ord` chocks on non-BMP char

Comment: Does `ord()` choke on non-BMP chars? `[ord(c) for c in u'\U00020000']` works fine for me, and the values in the resulting list are both >= 32 because they're surrogate pairs.

Comment: Clarification: you're right that `ord(u'\U00020000')` will fail, at least on UCS2 builds of Python, but using `ord(c)` is fine in this case because iterating over the string always gives chars <= 65535.

Answer (score 7):

And for Python 2, with the builtin `translate`:

```
import string
all_bytes = string.maketrans('', '')  # String of 256 characters with (byte) value 0 to 255

line.translate(all_bytes, all_bytes[:32])  # All bytes < 32 are deleted (the second argument lists the bytes to delete)
```

Answer (score 2):

You modify the line during iterating over it. Something like `''.join([x for x in line if ord(x) >= 32])`

Answer (score 2):

```
filter(string.printable[:-5].__contains__,line)
```

Comment: that's limited to the ascii set.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all the above and it didn't help. In my case, I had to remove Unicode 'LRM' chars:

Finally I found this solution that did the job:

```
df["AMOUNT"] = df["AMOUNT"].str.encode("ascii", "ignore")
df["AMOUNT"] = df["AMOUNT"].str.decode('UTF-8')
```

Reference [here](https://pythonguides.com/remove-unicode-characters-in-python/).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove a specific control character, you can do

```
line.replace("\x02", "")
```

Where `\x02` is the code of the character, in this case STX (start of text). You can find these codes for example [here](https://symbl.cc/en/unicode/blocks/basic-latin/).

Answer (score 0):

In `Python`>=3.5 there is a built-in method `str.isprintable()` that will return `False` for any character in the `Other` category of `Unicode` except for the ASCII space (0x20) which is considered printable:

```py
def remove_control_characters(s: str) -> str:
   return "".join(c for c in s if c.isprintable())

print(remove_control_characters("a bc"))  # a bc
print(remove_control_characters("a b\nc"))  # a bc
```

If the intent is to *replace* the non-printable characters, then the function can be modified to:

```py
def replace_control_characters(s: str) -> str:
    return "".join(c if c.isprintable() else f"\\u{ord(c):04x}" for c in s)

print(replace_control_characters("a bc"))  # a bc
print(replace_control_characters("a b\nc"))  # a b\u000ac
```

This replacement function is based on the [`minbpe` implementation](https://github.com/karpathy/minbpe/blob/f50ad93aa65072ac23e0a7e0bbc64c9c4e26cc4a/minbpe/base.py#L54C26-L54C45).