# Remove special characters from the string

Tags: python

In the following string how to remove all the special characters

```
str1="0Cell Phones: Smartphone,\x02\x05\x0e\x02\x05Mobile Phone - Best Buy13AT&T Wireless: AT&T Phones & Cell Phone Plans - Best Buy4\x02\x05\x0e\x02\x05Cell Phones: Smartphone, Mobile Phone - Best Buy1\x02\x05\x0e\x02\x05AT&T Wireless: AT&T Phones & Cell Phone Plans - Best Buy"
```

Comment: What do you call "special character"?

Comment: "All characters are special." - Tom Christiansen

Comment: :) i meant the characters that were ti be removed are \x021\x05.......

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing control characters from a string in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324790/removing-control-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: What about the `1` in there?, `\x02` is one character, so is `\x05` and there is a `1` in between.

Comment: k i have corrected the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord):

```
In [35]: str1="0Cell Phones: Smartphone,\x02\x05\x0e\x02\x05Mobile Phone - Best Buy13AT&T Wireless: AT&T Phones & Cell Phone Plans - Best Buy4\x02\x05\x0e\x02\x05Cell Phones: Smartphone, Mobile Phone - Best Buy1\x02\x05\x0e\x02\x05AT&T Wireless: AT&T Phones & Cell Phone Plans - Best Buy"

In [36]: "".join(x for x in str1 if 31 < ord(x) <127)

Out[36]: '0Cell Phones: Smartphone,Mobile Phone - Best Buy13AT&T Wireless: AT&T Phones & Cell Phone Plans - Best Buy4Cell Phones: Smartphone, Mobile Phone - Best Buy1AT&T Wireless: AT&T Phones & Cell Phone Plans - Best Buy'
```

First 32 are non-printing characters, this range includes `return` ,`backspace` etc and `32-127` are the printable ASCII characters.

`128-255`: extended ASCII

`ord()` returns this integer value for a single character and we can filter it by `31 < ord(x) <127`.

[image]

Comment: yes great but but what does ord(x) stand for?

Comment: note: you can use `31 < ord(x) < 128`

Comment: @Rajeev it's a built-in http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord.

Comment: where did u get the list?

Comment: @Rajeev http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII or http://www.asciitable.com/.