# regexpresion cannot match special symbols in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string: `s = "we are \xaf\x06OK\x03family, good"`, and I want to substitute the `\xaf`,`\x06` and `\x03` with '', the regexpresion is `pat = re.compile(r'\\[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+')`, but it cannnot match anything. The code is in belows:

```
pat = re.compile(r'\\[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+')
s = "we are \xaf\x06OK\x03family, good"
print(s)
print(re.sub(pat, '', s))
```

The result is

`we are ¯OKfamily, good 
we are ¯OKfamily, good`,

But how can I get `we are OK family, good`

Comment: Look at [your string](https://ideone.com/xL4LHd), it has no *literal* `\xaf`, etc. [Your regex](https://regex101.com/r/atDC2s/1) does not find any match in it.

Comment: Can I match it?

Comment: You can't match text that is missing in the string.

Comment: If you want to remove all control characters, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324790/removing-control-characters-from-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the basic but common mistake of confusing the representation of a string in Python source code with its actual value.

There are a number of escape codes in Python which do not represent themselves verbatim in regular strings in source code.  For example, `"\n"` represents a single newline character, even though the Python notation occupies two characters.  The backslash is used to introduce this notation.  There are a number of dedicated escape codes like `\r`, `\a`, etc, and a generalized notation `\x01` which allows you to write any character code in hex notation (`\n` is equivalent to `\x0a`,  `\r`  is equivalent to `\x0d`, etc).  To represent a literal backslash character, you need to escape it with another backslash: `"\\"`.

In a "raw string", no backslash escapes are supported; so `r"\n"` represents a string containing two characters, a literal backslash `\` and a literal lowercase `n`.  You could equivalently write `"\\n"` using non-raw string notation.  The `r` prefix is not part of the string, it just tells Python how to interpret the string between the following quotes (i.e. no interpretation at all; every character represents itself verbatim).

It is not clear from your question which of these interpretations you actually need, so I will present solutions for both.

Here is a literal string containing actual backslashes:

```
pat = re.compile(r'\\[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+')
s = r"we are \xaf\x06OK\x03family, good"
print(s)
print(re.sub(pat, '', s))
```

Here is a string containing control characters and non-ASCII characters, and a regex substitution to remove them:

```
pat = re.compile(r'[\x00-\x1f\x80-\xff]+')
s = "we are \xaf\x06OK\x03family, good"
print(s)
print(re.sub(pat, '', s))
```

An additional complication is that the regex engine has its own internal uses for backslashes; we generally prefer to use raw strings for regexes in order to not have Python and the regex engine both interpreting backslashes (sometimes in incompatible ways).

Comment: Sorry, stupid copy/paste mistake, code updated, try now.

Answer (score 2):

you have to consider your input `string s` as raw string then this work, see below example:

```
pat = re.compile(r'\\[xX][0-9a-fA-F].')
s = r"we are \xaf\x06OK\x03family, good"
print(s)
print(re.sub(pat, '', s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
pat = re.compile(r'[^\w\d\s,]+')
s = "we are \xaf\x06OK\x03family, good"
print(' '.join(map(lambda x: x.strip(), pat.split(s))))
#=> we are OK family, good
```

Used reverse match, remove(split by) any characters that are not what you wanted.