# How to replace hex value in a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, encoding, utf-8, hex

While importing data from a flat file, I noticed some embedded hex-values in the string (`<0x00>`, `<0x01>`).

I want to replace them with specific characters, but am unable to do so. Removing them won't work either.
What it looks like in the exported flat file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxiEl.png
Another example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJR8G.png

---

This is what I've tried: 
(and mind, `<0x01>` represents a none-editable entity. It's not recognized here.)

```py
import io
with io.open('1.txt', 'r+', encoding="utf-8") as p:
    s=p.read()
# included in case it bears any significance
```

```py
import re
import binascii

s = "Some string with hex: <0x01>"

s = s.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
# throws e.g.: >>> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 114: invalid start byte

s = re.sub(r'<0x01>', r'.', s)
s = re.sub(r'\\0x01', r'.', s)
s = re.sub(r'\\\\0x01', r'.', s)
s = s.replace('\0x01', '.')
s = s.replace('<0x01>', '.')
s = s.replace('0x01', '.')
```

or something along these lines in hopes to get a grasp of it while iterating through the whole string:

```py
for x in s:
    try:
        base64.encodebytes(x)
        base64.decodebytes(x)
        s.strip(binascii.unhexlify(x))
        s.decode('utf-8')
        s.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
    except:
        pass
```

Nothing seems to get the job done.

I'd expect the characters to be replacable with the methods I've dug up, but they are not. What am I missing?
NB: I have to preserve umlauts (äöüÄÖÜ)

-- edit:

Could I introduce the hex-values in the first place when exporting? If so, is there a way to avoid that?

```py
with io.open('out.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as temp:
    temp.write(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the images, these are actually control characters.
Your editor displays them in this greyed-out way showing you the value of the bytes using hex notation.
You don't have the characters "0x01" in your data, but really a single byte with the value `1`, so `unhexlify` and friends won't help.

In Python, these characters can be produced in string literals with escape sequences using the notation `\xHH`, with two hexadecimal digits.
The fragment from the first image is probably equal to the following string:

```
"sich z\x01 B. irgendeine"
```

Your attempts to remove them were close.
`s = s.replace('\x01', '.')` should work.

Comment: Yep, that did it … thank you. Fyi, I figured out that I introduced the characters myself during re.sub replacements. For example, `re.sub('(?<=\w)([,.!?;])(?=\w)', u'\1 ', s)` backreferenced the replaced character and thus introduced the "single byte with the value 1". The regex-module apparently does a better job at this: `'(?<=\w)\p{;,\.!\?}(?=\w)'`. (via [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324790/removing-control-characters-from-a-string-in-python))

Comment: I don't think `re.sub` with `\n` backreferences will introduce control characters. That is, unless you mispell the backreferences as `\x01`, of course. Btw, if this answer solved the problem you described, consider accepting it through the tick on the left.