# Removing two non printable characters from a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, character-encoding, backslash

I am getting a text like below by reading a word file

```
Exe Command\r\x07
```

My desired text is

```
Exe Command
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92488/1113684) but it gives me

```
 Exe Command\r
```

How can i remove 2 any backslash characters? I would like a speed friendly solution because I have thousands of inputs like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` method twice.

```
In [1]: myStr.replace("\r", "").replace("\x07", "")
Out[1]: 'Exe Command'
```

If this isn't working, you can try using raw string

```
In [1]: myStr.replace(r"\r", "").replace(r"\x07", "")
Out[1]: 'Exe Command'
```

**EDIT:** As per comment, for removing any of those control characters, use [this post's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19016117/10473393) solution.

```
import unicodedata
def remove_control_characters(s):
    return "".join(ch for ch in s if unicodedata.category(ch)[0]!="C")
```

All credits for this solution goes to Alex Quinn.

Comment: I want a way to remove any backslash characters from the string and not those specific ones.

Comment: Hello @AnubhavJhalani, i updated the post. Please check if Alex Quinn's solution works for you.